# Return one of two columns in a view - whichever one is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with three columns:

```
ColumnA          ColumnB         ColumnC
AAA               NULL            123
BBB               222             NULL
CCC               NULL            NULL
```

I would like to create a SELECT statement which will return ColumnA, and then a second column which will either show the value of ColumnB unless ColumnB is null; otherwise it will show the value of ColumnC, even it it's NULL.  Can I use an IF statement for that?  Something like:

```
SELECT ColumnA, 
IF(ColumnB IS NULL, ColumnC, ColumnB)
FROM table
```

**If I get this working, the next step would be to return the value of a joined column instead of ColumnB.  In effect the IF statement would be

```
IF(table.ColumnB IS NULL, table.ColumnC, table2.ColumnD)
```

Comment: @JNK it's SQL Server version 9.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading to the end of your question it sounds like you need to use `CASE`

```
CASE WHEN table.ColumnB IS NULL 
     THEN table.ColumnC 
     ELSE table2.ColumnD 
END AS Whatever
```

Answer (score 16):

Use `COALESCE`

`SELECT ColumnA, COALESCE(ColumnB, ColumnC) as 'Value'`

Comment: COALESCE is ANSI, and supported by MySQL 4+, Oracle 9i+, SQL Server 2000+.  Very safe bet

Comment: This worked great, thanks!  However I awarded it to @Martin since his solution addressed the next step as well.