# SQL Select colmn from other table only if data exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables and I'm selecting data from the first table. If the condition is meet(Alias type = 2) and the data in second table for the id from the first table exist the I want to select the column from the second table. Here is data to explain more:

**Table 1**

```
id | Name         | Location  
---+--------------+---------  
34 |John Smith    |NewYork  
36 |Mike Smith    |London  
45 |Bob Smith     |Los Angeles
```

**Table 2**

```
id | Alias             | Alias type     
---+-------------------+-------  
36 |Warren Johnson     |1  
36 |William Williams   |2
```

Wanted results if alias type = 2

```
id |Name               | Location   
---+-------------------+---------  
34 |John Smith         |NewYork  
36 |William Williams   |London  
45 |Bob Smith          |Los Angeles
```

Can you help me write query to get the wanted results? Tell me if I need to explain more. I'm using a SQL Server database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return one of two columns in a view - whichever one is not null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199360/return-one-of-two-columns-in-a-view-whichever-one-is-not-null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `left outer join` onto Table2, and then [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) the Alias and Name results like this:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, COALESCE(Table2.Alias, Table1.Name) AS Name, 
    Table1.Location
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID AND Table2.AliasType = 2
```

`COALESCE` works by finding the first non-null value in the supplied values.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this -- you just need to use `CASE`:

```
SELECT T1.Id, 
   CASE WHEN T2.Alias IS NOT NULL THEN T2.Alias ELSE T1.Name END as Name,
   t1.Location
FROM Table1 T1
   LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id AND T2.AliasType = 2
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8efa3/1).

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The COALESCE function will let you have a fall-back expression so that the name from table 2 is used if it exists, and the name from table 1 is used otherwise.  The LEFT outer join only joins table 2 when the rows exist, and t2.name is null if no record was joined.

`SELECT t1.id, COALESCE(t2.name, t1.name), t1.location FROM [Table 1] as t1 LEFT JOIN [Table 2] as t2 on t1.id=t2.id and t2.[alias type]=2`